# Reading a text file into ListView (app adds to ListView twice)?

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm relatively new to Android Studio. Basically what I'm trying to do is create a sort of a history file for a QR scanner. Anything I scan goes into a History.txt file. It's working but not the way I intended. This was the result of checking the history after the first scan:

[image: Result of First Scan]

And this is what happens when I check the second scan:

[image: Result of Second Scan]

This is my OutputWriter code:

```
try {
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("History.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
    outputStreamWriter.write(rawResult.getText()); // the scan result
    outputStreamWriter.append("\n\r");
    outputStreamWriter.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
}
```

And this is the Activity that displays the history:

```
public class ResultsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView ResultsListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
        ResultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ResultsListView);
        readFromFile();
    }

    private String readFromFile() {

        String ret = "";

        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(); // stores lines from text file.

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("History.txt");

            if ( inputStream != null ) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null ) {
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                    lines.add(stringBuilder.toString());
                }

                inputStream.close();

                // put results in ListView
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lines);
                ResultsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File not found: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
        }

        return ret;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure why things are appearing twice in the ListView. Looked at it for sometime but didn't see anything. My apologies if this happens to be a simple error. I'm still getting familiar with Android Studio. Any bit of help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: have you check the <code> rawResult.getText() </code> result yet ? function readFromFile() is ok. I think your input wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at this code:

```
            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                lines.add(stringBuilder.toString());
            }
```

You are appending a line to `stringBuilder`, then adding the entire string to the adapter so some lines will get added multiple times.  I think you mean to do this:

```
            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                lines.add(receiveString);
            }
```

Maybe you don't really need `stringBuilder`.